# Multiple groups when iterating in a template file

Tags: ansible

This article from Ansible.com shows how you can iterate over a group inside of a template file:  https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201957887-How-to-loop-over-a-list-of-hosts-in-a-group-inside-of-a-template-

It shows the following code:

```
{% for host in groups['db_servers'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

It works beautifully, but the servers I want to iterate over are defined by being in multiple groups.  So imagine that I want to iterate over all of the servers that are in BOTH the db_servers and qa groups.  How can I do this?

I tried to specify the intersection of the group in the same manner I do in my playbook, but that doesn't work.  So, when I try:

```
{% for host in groups['db_servers:&qa'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: [54.173.247.115] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'db_servers:&qa'", 'failed': True}
```

Any suggestions on how to iterate over multiple groups in a template file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible has the `intersect` filter. See [Set Theory Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters).

```
{% for host in groups['db_servers'] | intersect(groups['qa']) %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you want to list hosts from multiple different groups, use the `union` filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your loop in another for the two server groups:

```
{% for svrs in ['db_servers', 'qa'] %}
  {% for host in groups[svrs] %}
    {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This ain't an intersection. That would simply loop over all hosts of both groups.